# Unable to generate Controller for Entity using SqlServer CE 4.0: ScaffoldingConnectionFactory Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am getting the feel of **SqlServer CE 4.0** to use with MVC 3 without installation. Things are going fine. I have successfully integrated Troy Goode's [MembershipStarterKit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit) and also ErikEJ's [SqlServerCEMembership](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2010/08/sql-server-compact-40-aspnet-membership.html) provider. Both are working find. Now I have a moder class:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime DOB{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Gender{get;set;}
}
```

I am also using `DBContext` class:

```
public class MyDbContext: DBContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students{get;set;}
}
```

When I try to add a controller by selecting the `Student` class as model, I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MVCProject1.Models.Student'. There was an error 
generating 'ScaffoldingConnectionFactory. Try Rebuilding your project.
```

I have tried both 4.3.0 and 4.3.2 versions of package EntityFrameWork.SqlServerCompact but am still getting the error. What is wrong with my approach?

EDIT:- I have tried again and again after rebuilding the project, by uninstalling/re-installing packages.

Comment: I know this may sound rude, but have you rebuilt your project before trying to create the controller like the error sais?

Comment: Check if you don't have Entity Framework CTP5 installed. Uninstall it if you do and create new project. That worked in my case at least ;)

Comment: @lucask nope no CTP only SQL CE 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out to be a matter of confused extensions. I had installed `EntityFramework` and `EFCodeFirst`, `EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact`. This seemed to cause problem. I uninstalled `EFCodeFirst`, `EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact` including dependencies and then `EntityFramework` also.

Clean installing `EntityFramework`, `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` resolved the issue.